# How do I provide parameters to "wsimport" for JAX-WS from Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jax-ws, wsimport

I need to override the `wsdlLocation` parameter for `wsimport` (when using the JAX-WS webservice option in IntelliJ IDEA) to a relative path at the point of creating these files, as well as specifying where the output classes are generated. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Jetbrains and I understand this is not currently possible, and i've logged it as a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168127

However, I now have a workaround by creating a new menu item using the External Tools setting (**File -> Settings -> Tools -> External Tools**) along with macros for that dialog.

The image at this link describes my workaround: [Create Tool Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p4sa.jpg). Unfortunately, there's no macro for specifying a folder so the `-d` option for `wsimport` is still directed at the source folder. I'm sure you can get creative with this, but it meets my needs right now.